# Insert Datestamp automatically when a new row is added

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, zapier

I'm collecting data from form submissions on our website via Zapier. Zapier adds a new row to Google Sheets automatically each time the form is submitted and populates data to columns B:L. The column A is where I'd like have a datestamp (YYYY-MM-DD) for each row.

Currently I have this script which I found online. This works if I edit the Sheet manually. However, the script doesn't trigger when Zapier pushes the data to the Sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HnxQmAQlLVLsLG_RKJwkmzzObwlwe8hHlAHd65zLjSc/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+2";
  var timestamp_format = "YYYY-mm-dd"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Country";
  var timeStampColName = "Date";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

How should I edit this script in order to make it work with automatic row updates? Or does someone have an another script for me to try?

Comment: Can you share exactly what the flow of your Zapier steps are? Is it Zapier Webhooks as the trigger then an Add Row to Google Sheet as the action step?

Answer (score 0):

The `onEdit` function [does not trigger when used with the API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). So, the short answer would be no.

However, you could try to modify you Zappier hook to also add an timestamp.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, in this case modifying the Zapier hook won't help since it cannot send the timestamp to Google Sheets.